# How to remove period after Biblatex footnote citation

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

I can't get rid of the period after each footnote citation created by `\autocite`. I have tried to redefine `\autocite` and a few other things but nothing has worked for me. Is there a consistent and easy way to remove the dot after all footnotes created by `\autocite`?

MWE:

Bibliography.bib

```
@book{a,
  title={Test book},
  author={Author, Test},
  year={2000},
  address={New York},
  publisher={IMG}
}
```

Tex.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,autocite=footnote,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\begin{document}

Hi there\autocite{a}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See `\bibfootnotewrapper ` in the documentation.

Comment: Haha, oh I'm embarrassed, thank you! I did look for quite some time in that manual you know! If you'll make an answer out of it, I'll accept it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `\bibfootnotewrapper` in the documentation.